# How to Mock HttpContext to set Response.Cookie.Append() in UnitTest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core, cookies

I need to mock HttpContext and append cookies to validate in controller.

Here is the unit Test I am trying but its failing with null exception.

```
HomeController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();
HomeController.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
HomeController.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("mycookie", cookieValue, cookieOptions);
```

Here is the my controler where I am checking cooking null.

```
 public async Task<myDto> Identify() {

    // Get identifier from client
    var identifier = identifiersService.GetIdentifier(HttpContext);
    if (!await identifiersService.IsValidAsync(identifier)) {
        if (HttpContext != null && HttpContext.Request.Cookies["mycookie"] != null) {
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("mycookie");
        }
        throw new MyException(Factory.INVALID);
    }
```

Any suggestion on how I can pass cookie from unittest to Controller to test. Thank you

Comment: @Peter Csala Request.Cookies works fine. if cookies is available then I need to delete the cookie. How I can I mock response.cookies.delete(). This is throwing null exception. Any suggestion on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the cookie on the response while you are checking it on the request.

1. Mock the Cookies collection on the request
2. Pass the mocked `HttpContext` to the `ControllerContext`

```
var cookiesMock = new Mock<IRequestCookieCollection>();
cookiesMock.SetupGet(c => c["mycookie"]).Returns(cookieValue);

var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContext>();
httpContextMock.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request.Cookies).Returns(cookiesMock.Object);

HomeController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
{
    HttpContext = httpContextMock.Object
};
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

> If cookies is available then I need to delete the cookie. How I can I mock `Response.Cookies.Delete()`?

Quite similarly what we did with the request cookies

```
var responseCookiesMock = new Mock<IResponseCookies>();
responseCookiesMock.Setup(c => c.Delete("mycookie"))
                   .Verifiable();
httpContextMock.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response.Cookies)
               .Returns(responseCookiesMock.Object);
```

So, the full code would look like this

```
const string CookieKey = "mycookie";
var requestCookiesMock = new Mock<IRequestCookieCollection>();
requestCookiesMock.SetupGet(c => c[CookieKey]).Returns(cookieValue);

var responseCookiesMock = new Mock<IResponseCookies>();
responseCookiesMock.Setup(c => c.Delete(CookieKey)).Verifiable();

var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContext>();
httpContextMock.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request.Cookies)
                .Returns(requestCookiesMock.Object);
httpContextMock.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response.Cookies)
                .Returns(responseCookiesMock.Object);

HomeController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
{
    HttpContext = httpContextMock.Object
};
```

Comment: Request.Cookies works fine.  if cookies is available then I need to delete the cookie. How I can I mock response.cookies.delete(). This is throwing null exception. Any idea on this. Thank you.    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("mycookie");

Comment: @Mukesh I've just updated my post to address the deletion part as well. If you have find my post useful please consider to upvote it. Have a great day!